# How Many Cyclic Subgroups of order $10$ are there in $\mathbb{Z}_{100}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{25}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

How Many Cyclic Subgroups of order $10$ are there in $\mathbb{Z}_{100}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{25}$?

I have calculated that there are $24$ elements of order $10$
I know that in a cyclic subgroup of order $10$, There are $4$ element of order $10$

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Well, there should be 6 groups by what you say, right?

Comment: I am not able to get how it will be $6$, and why? yes the answer is $6$

Comment: Every group will account for 4 elements of order 10, so the number of groups is $24/4 = 6$

Comment: Happy Diwali Sir! Thank you,  It was quite easy, I was thinking two different cyclic group can have same element of order $10$ blah blah

Comment: Happy Diwali :)

Answer (score 2):

By using [GAP 4.6.5](http://www.gap-system.org) these desired subgroup are enclosed computationally. Below is needed codes for doing this job:

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b");;
     a:=f.1;; b:=f.2;;
     s:=f/[a^100,b^25,a*b*a^(-1)*b^(-1)];;
     e:=AllSubgroups(s);;
     c:=Filtered(e,t->IsCyclic(t)=true);;
     Filtered(c,t->Order(t)=10);

 Group([ b^5, a^-50 ]),
 Group([ a^-9*b^10*a^-1 ]),
 Group([ a^-9*b^-10*a^-1 ]),
 Group([ a^8*b^-5*a^2 ]),
 Group([ a^8*b^5*a^2 ]), 
 Group([ a^-10 ]) ]
```

Comment: Nice to use the latest GAP version at the time of answer! [GAP 4.7.2](http://www.gap-system.org/Releases/index.html) just become available!

Comment: Looks like we should make a generic answer how to deal with questions like this in GAP, since this is really becoming a F.A.Q. ...

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Thanks for letting me know that availability. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! You've got all the pieces you need; now it's just putting those pieces together.

Since you've correctly determined that there are $24$ elements of order $10$, and since you've correctly observed that every cyclic group of order $10$ contains $4$ elements of order $10$, then we need only divide: $$\text{There are $\;\dfrac{24}{4}$} = \text{$6\;$ cyclic subgroups of order $10\,$ in $\,\mathbb{Z}_{100}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{25}$}$$